# Perl: buscar nombres propios en un texto

Tags: perl

He hecho este programa para identificar nombres propios en un texto.

Este es mi texto:

```
Vine con Pablo a la casa.
Pedro me lo dijo.
Fui con Mariano García a la cena.
Cristina Maña no come.
No me cuentes con el AGG.
Ay que ver con Ana García Villa.
Soraya Puerto de Santamaría no es Ok.
```

De momento, solo quiero que me coja nombres propios dentro de la oración.

Mi código es este:

```js
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
$texto = "Corpus.txt";
open(INFILE, "<", $texto) or die "Can't open < input.txt: $!";
while (my $row = <INFILE>) 
{
    #chomp $row;
    push @array, $row;   
    #print "$row\n";    
}

foreach $linea (@array) {
    # Una NE unitoken dentro de la oración. Ejemplo: Vine con Pablo a la casa.
    $linea =~ m/\s([A-Z][a-z]+)\s/;
    $pablo = $1;
    print("$pablo\n");
    #print $l;
 }
```

Lo que no entiendo es por qué cuando hago print $pablo, me devuelve este resultado:

```
Pablo
Pablo
Mariano
Mariano
Mariano
Ana
Puerto
Puerto
```

No lo entiendo. ¿Por qué evalúa la primera línea más de una vez, y sin embargo la línea 6, donde está el nombre de Ana, solo lo saca una vez?

Como es obvio, apenas llevo unas semanas aprendiendo a programar. Y el programa está haciendo algo que no es lo que yo pienso que debería hacer. A ver si alguien me puede indicar dónde está el "error de fundamento".

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En la primera línea del texto, el programa se encuentra con "Pablo", y se lo guarda en la variable $pablo.

Al llegar a la segunda línea, resulta que no se cumple el patrón de la expresión regular ("Pedro" está al principio de la línea, por lo que no hay un '\s' delante de él). Entonces, la expresión regular falla, y por lo tanto, no se actualiza el valor de $1, que sigue valiendo lo anterior, "Pablo".

Lo mismo pasa con el resto de líneas. "Mariano" aparece tres veces porque las dos lineas siguientes a donde se encuentra el primer "Mariano" tampoco coinciden con el patrón.

Una forma de solucionarlo es hacer una pregunta para ver si la expresión regular ha encontrado algo:

```perl
if ($linea =~ m/\s([A-Z][a-z]+)\s/) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```